# Setting another month as default in jQuery UI datepicker before display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In my situation, I have to set the month to last month as default.

The default month for the datepicker is current month. But I want it to be last month or other month as default showing. How can I make it?

Such as: "2010-09" as the default.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`defaultDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) option when creating the datepicker:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '-2m'
});
```

By passing in a string like this we can set the default date to another one relative to the current date. Alternatively, the option also accepts a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) object:

```
defaultDate: new Date(2010, 8, 1)
```

or a string in the same format as the format currently defined:

```
defaultDate: '1/9/2010'
```

All of the above will give you a default date in September. The month in the `Date` constructor starts from zero, so 8 will give you September.

Answer (score 9):

I think you actually want this when you're only showing 1 month at a time.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ showCurrentAtPos: 1 });
```

If you use defaultDate it will highlight that particular day, this method just shows the previous month with nothing selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.