# JQuery UI Datepicker Default Month Issue

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to set the default year and month displayed on a datepicker according to other values entered on the form.

Does anyone know how to set the year and month without actually calling setDate() ?

Thanks,

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170880/setting-another-month-as-default-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-before-display

Answer (score 0):

Use the defaultDate method not setDate